# Unity - Скроллинг камеры в редакторе без участия мыши

Tags: unity3d

Мне необходим управлять камерой **в окне сцены**. Необходимо это делать **не с помощью мыши** (скорллинг колёсиком) для приближения и удаления от/к объекту, а **с помощью клавиш**, потому что возможности управления скроллингом нет.

Можно ли переопределить клавиши? Или, быть может, уже есть клавиши для этого?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Comment: Нет, не в режиме запуска, а просто управление самой средой Unity, к примеру в режиме 3d приближение и удаление от объекта.

Comment: Ааа, дошло,сейчас гляну

Comment: Нашёл решение своей проблемы без добавления скрипта. В 3d режиме можно использовать Shift + Num 4,6,8,2.

Answer (score 1):

В 3D режиме можно использовать:

- **Shift + Num 4,6,8,2;**
- **Mouse Right + W / S / A / D.**